# Method --> Action --> Mutation --> State issue

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource, vue-router, vue-component, vuex

My function that's supposed to iteratively insert JSON into each element of a particular level of nested JSON using parameters from itself is duplicating the first object returned and inserting it into each nested parameter. See screenshots and code below to get a feel for what I'm doing.

Basically I have a nested JSON object within the state, and need to iteratively append to a nested property of each 'row' of the existing object using an action that returns JSON from an API then a mutation that updates the state.

The problem lies within the mutation I think. I've deduced my function is duplicating the first JSON object returned from the API. See Action and Mutation functions below, along with API function and structure of JSON.

http://api.capecodcommission.org/docs/index.html#sumofannualcapitaltotalsfortreatment

Function within a particular component run using v-for:

```
methods: {
    costTotal () {
      return this.updateFinTotals(this.treatment.treatmentId,this.costType.treatTotal,this.costType.financeOption,this.treatment.relativeStartYear,this.costType.finDur,this.costType.prinFor)
    }
  }
```

Running function, viewing JSON:

```
<td class="text-center">
    {{ costTotal  }}
    {{ costType.annualized.sumOfAnnualCapitalTotals }}
</td>
```

V-for Loop:

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="(index, costType) in treatment.costTypes | filterBy 'true' in 'financeable'" is="cost-type-table-row-finance" :cost-type="costType"></tr> 
</tbody>
```

API function:

```
getSumOfAnnualCapitalTotals (treatmentId, costToFinance, financeOption, relativeStartYear, financeDuration, principalForgivenessRate) {
    let data = {
      treatmentId: treatmentId,
      costToFinance: costToFinance,
      financeOption: financeOption,
      relativeStartYear: relativeStartYear,
      financeDuration: financeDuration,
      principalForgivenessRate: principalForgivenessRate
    } 

    return Vue.http.post(API_ROOT + 'sumOfAnnualCapitalTotalsForTreatment', data)
  }
```

Action: Pulls JSON from API, dispatches mutation function.

```
export const updateFinTotals = function ({ dispatch, state }, treatmentId, costToFinance, financeOption, relativeStartYear, financeDuration, principalForgivenessRate) {

  api.getSumOfAnnualCapitalTotals( treatmentId, costToFinance, financeOption, relativeStartYear, financeDuration, principalForgivenessRate ).then(function (response) {

    dispatch('UPDATE_ANNUALIZED', response.data)

  }, function (response) {

    console.log(response)
  })
}
```

Mutation: Updates state with JSON.

```
UPDATE_ANNUALIZED (state, annualized) {
    for (var i = 0; i < state.scenario.treatments.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < state.scenario.treatments[i].costTypes.length; j++) {
        state.scenario.treatments[i].costTypes[j]["annualized"] = annualized
      }
    }
  }
```

**EDIT: PICS BELOW**

Component: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuNsZ.jpg

JSON Structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzNwi.jpg

Comment: It's hard to deduce where the issues lies in your code with what you have provided. Could you create a simple example so that we can test it for ourselves? Also, I'm still not completely clear what it is that is not working and how it should work instead. Could you please explain the issue itself in more detail?

Comment: Hey @nils, thanks for your response. Check the screenshots I'd added below the code. You'll have the zoom into the JSON image as it's a huge object.

I've got a function that returns { sumOfAnnualCapitalTotals: #### } where #### is a sum based on costType parameters from each treatments[i].costTypes[j], and I'm sticking that returned object within each treatments[i].costTypes[j].annualized, but it's simply duplicating the first iteration over all [i] and [j]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your API returns *one* value (for *one* cost-type of *one* treatment)

Example from linked API docs:

```
{"sumOfAnnualCapitalTotals":150374.9849625}
```

but you assign it to *all* cost-types of *all* treatments with the for loop in the mutation:

```
for (var i = 0; i < state.scenario.treatments.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < state.scenario.treatments[i].costTypes.length; j++) {
    state.scenario.treatments[i].costTypes[j]["annualized"] = annualized
  }
}
```

what you should be doing is pass the `treatmentID` and cost type (which, I sherlock-holmed, is called `costToFinance`) from the action to the mutation, then filter the state for the matching object, and update only that:

```
UPDATE_ANNUALIZED (state, treadmentId, costToFinance, annualized) {

  const treatment = state.treatments.find((t) => t.treatmentId === treatmentId)

  const currCostType = treatment.costTypes.find((costType) => costType.Id === costToFinance)

  currCostType.annualized = annualized
}
```

The problem is that your JSON doesn't seem to have any ID for the costTypes to `find` it by, but that's for you to figure out.

Comment: What's the best way to dispatch more than response.data from the action?
I'm already obtaining treatmentId and could probably use costType.name for the mutation .find(), but need to figure out how to pass those along with response.data from the action to the mutation.